# Which types of accommodations are affected by Lisbon's municipal tax?

Tags: taxis, portugal, lisbon

Which types of accommodations are affected by Lisbon's municipal tax?

I read on http://www.cm-lisboa.pt/uploads/media/flyerTMT_UK_web.pdf   ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170327210046/http://www.cm-lisboa.pt/uploads/media/flyerTMT_UK_web.pdf)):

> Who pays?
>   The tax on overnight stays is
>   applied to guests over the age
>   of thirteen, per person and
>   per overnight stay, up to a
>   maximum of 7 nights per stay.
>
> **Where?
>   Per overnight stay in tourist
>   resorts and local accommodation
>   establishments (hotels, hostels,
>   local accommodation, etc.).**
>
> What is the value of
>   the tax?
>   1 €per night up to a maximum of
>   7 € (7 overnight stays in a row, per
>   person].
>
> Who is exempt?
>   Guests whose stay is motivated
>   by the need for medical services
>   during the period of hospitalization/
>   treatment+ 1 additional night [and
>   that of accompanying party).

It is unclear to me what types of accommodations the tax affects. E.g., if I stay at a friend's place, sleep in a public place ( beach / park), or in my car, do I have to pay the tax?

Comment: How would they even know you've slept at a friend's place? :)

Comment: I think "hotels, hostels, local accommodation, etc" is quite clear, I guess etc is there just not to enumerate camping fields, bed & breakfasts, pousadas etc. I don't see how it would mean friend's place

Comment: @Kuba Isn't a friend's place a local accommodation?

Comment: @JonathanReez Tough to see indeed unless they are already looking for it (or with a good automated citizen tracking system).  But there could be some more borderline cases e.g. sleeping through CouchSurfing.com

Answer (score 2):

You have to be realistic about these things. Noone is going to keep up a police force over a euro a night. So yes, hotels and such places will pay it for you, even [Airbnb](https://www.airbnb.ca/help/article/653/in-what-areas-is-occupancy-tax-collection-and-remittance-by-airbnb-available) will force it but if there's not otherwise a money-collecting, revenue-reporting system in place for the place, you won't.