# Airbnb guests meaning

Tags: rental, airbnb

I am trying to book an Airbnb, the listings have a x guests. Does that mean I am only booking a room of the property, and the property can have extra x foreign guests hosted by the host plus me?

Or I rent the whole property, and guests are up to me to bring or not to bring?

Comment: There are different types of listings on AirBnb. Some are for whole properties (flat or house), some are for private rooms inside a property (but you share communal spaces like the kitchen etc.), and some are for beds in a shared space. You can filter the type of listing when doing a search. The meaning of the maximum number of guests will depend on the type of listing.

Comment: @Papa The listing should make clear whether the rental is the whole property or a room, and the maximum permitted number of guests (eg ‘1 room, 3 x guests, 2 beds’ means a maximum of 3 people in one room with 2 beds). Check the ‘house rules’ and contact the host prior to booking if you’re unsure (source: I am an AirBnB host).

Answer (score 4):

As it stands in the comments - there are different type of listings in AirBnB and it's easy to filter them.

[image]

The number of guests can play a role for the price - some AirBnB listings have additional fees for every guest after the Xth.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The guests are up to you to bring or not to bring. The number of guests includes you by the way, e.g. 2 guests = you + 1 friend. Also quite often the maximum number of guest isn't enforced (but some guests may end up sleeping on the floor/couch if you go over). In some cases (uncommon), the rent price depends on the number of guests you indicate. Also, in some jurisdictions (e.g., Peru I believe), each guest has to provide some ID to the host by law. Additionally, in some jurisdictions, a tax may have to be paid for each guest (e.g., [Lisbon's municipal tax](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/90638/1810)), in theory at least.

Comment: There may also be local rules that limit how many guests the property can have.

Comment: I have been asked for ID for each and every guest in Italy.